# Normalize the force added by AddForce to 3D object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a ball bouncing up and down my scene with the following script:

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public float globalGravity;

    Rigidbody ball;

    void Start()
    {
        ball = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 gravity = globalGravity * Vector3.up;
        ball.AddForce(gravity, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }

    void Force(float force)
    {
        ball.AddForce(Vector3.up * force, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {    
        Force(speed);
    }
}
```

If the ball hits a flat surface it's propelled upwards like the script implies, but I've found that if it hits a platform that is angled then the force applied is much weaker and the ball doesn't bounce as high.  Is there a reason for this, and a way I can get the force to be equal no matter what the angle of the surface it collides with is?

Comment: What's the purpose of adding anti-gravity force if no gravity is used (as you commented)? Does the ball drop if no gravity is applied? And if the ball doesn't drop how does collision occur?

Comment: I'm adding my own gravity in FixedUpdate

Comment: Ok. I deleted my post. Hope someone else have an answer. You can also give a try on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/